# Declare variable containing a live nodeList with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm declaring a variable containing a jQuery object in the following way `$current = $('.current')` at the beginning of my code. The problem is that my class `current` change frequently of node.

Here is [an exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/cTnSx/)

Is there a way to declare the selector at the beginning of the script and make it somehow more dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a way to declare a jQuery variable that is always up-to-date when you add/remove items from the DOM that match its selector.  That is not a feature that jQuery has.

There are many other ways to solve the problem of dynamically created elements though.  For example, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live nodeList that is kept up to date as the document changes.  And, of course, you can always just refresh your jQuery variable before using it with a fresh query of what is in the document at any given time.  This is the usual recommendation for any action that it triggered by a user because refreshing the query is plenty fast for user time and is guarenteed to be accurate as of the moment the action occurs and carries no risk of memory leaks due to dangling references.

In general, it is not a good idea to keep a jQuery variable around for awhile if objects in it are dynamcally created/removed because keeping the reference to them in the jQuery variable can prevent the garbage collector from cleaning up the memory from old objects (e.g. memory leaks) until the jQuery variable itself is removed.

Comment: I'm using that way http://jsfiddle.net/roine/cTnSx/4/, is it correct? At least it works

Answer (score 0):

If it's a feature you're really interested in obtaining for your front end, you could look at using an MVVM or MVC type framework like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Spine](http://spinejs.com/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) etc. They generally have the concept of declarative data-binding, so you can tie any variable to user input and vice-versa any displayed markup to any variable without having to muck about with updating yourself.

Here's an [excellent article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/) comparing some frameworks.

I'm a fan of Knockout myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you're declaring a variable like that it holds the jQuery object into memory until you release it or change it.  So if you call it you'll always get the value that it had when you first loaded it.

If you really need an updated jQuery object, you could just call it when you need it $('.current'), it will then recalculate the jQuery object and you can use a current set of elements.

However if you really need to do it this way for some reason I can't imagine, would this do the trick for you:

```
$current = function(){
    return $('.current');
    };
```

Then you could call $current() and you'd get your updated jQuery object.

Again I think doing it this way is silly unless you need to process the jquery object a certain way before you use it, other wise the best way is to just call the jQuery object $('.current') directly like I mentioned before....alot simpler.

**AMENDMENT**: I guess this might be useful  if you have a really annoyingly long jQuery object to call constanlty, something like `$('.class').has('.otherClass').find('.thirdClass').children('img.fourthClassIfYouCanBelieveIt:first');`

In that case yeah, I'd rather call $current()

Comment: This looks like what kennypu was trying to do in his first answer, but he forgot the `()` to actually call the function.

Comment: Like I said I don't see this being useful unless you have a super long to write jQuery object to call ALL THE TIME

Comment: This will give you an updated object to work with and is therefore as the question demands more dynamic, and more flexible than just calling document.getElementByClassName('whatevs')

Answer (score -1):

If you mean, make it so that the variable `$current` updates on its own, I don't think so. your best bet is to reset the variable after setting it again:

```
.... //your code:
 $(this).addClass('current');
$current = $('.current');
```

Comment: Your last edit is not correct.  You can't just use `$current` as an automatic function.  It's still just a variable that contains the result of executing your function.

Comment: hmm, odd, i tried it on the fiddle you he showed and it did what i expected. looks like you are right though.